# std::vector<uchar> to char* data loss

Tags: c++, vector, casting, type-conversion

I used `cv::imencode` to encode a `cv::Mat` as `image/jpeg` into a `vector<uchar>` now I want to convert that vector to type `char *`.

```
vector<uchar> buf;

// print buf to stdout to ensure that data is valid here
for (auto c : buf)
    cout << c << endl;

// cast vector to char
char *ch = reinterpret_cast<char*>(buf.data());

// print out value of char pointer
for(int i = 0; ch[i] != '\0'; i++)
    printf("log: %c\n", ch[i]);
```

The for loop over the vector is taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10750057/c-printing-out-the-contents-of-a-vector).
The cast from `std::vector<T>` to `char *` is taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254615/how-to-cast-vectorunsigned-char-to-char).

The problem is now that there seems to be some data loss during the type conversion. Whereas `buf` contains valid data I always only get the value `????` printed from `ch`.

**Any ideas what happened here?**

Comment: Sure there are only printable characters in the buffer?

Comment: Why cast to `char*` not `unsigned char*`?  What type of data is in `buf`?  What are you actually trying to do or is this just an interest question?

Comment: This is part of a [cgo](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/) module which does some image processing with [opencv](http://http://opencv.org). So `buf` contains this processed image as jpeg. However I think pasting the complete file would distract from the actual problem.

Comment: @ilent2 I need to cast to `char *` as cgo cannot export `unsigned char*` to go.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yes as I get some valid characters printed in the first loop.

Comment: What about changing the end condition of the second loop to `i < buf.size()`, just in case `buf` contains instances of `0x00`?

Comment: @bodokaiser The vector has name buf: vector<uchar> buf;  but in the next statement you are using name buffer char *ch = reinterpret_cast<char*>(buffer.data());

Comment: how is `cout << c << endl;` supposed to work when it is an encoded jpeg?

Comment: @MattMcNabb Assuming C++11 and `uchar` is equivalent to `unsigned char` that would just output a 8 bit number for each element in `buf`.

Comment: @ilent2 you are right `buf` contains the terminating character so that `ch` will not contain the whole data. Is there any simple workaround or should I recheck cgo for other possible types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you work with a vector, all is fine since à vector is a dynamic array with an explicit size. So it **can** contain null values.

But next, you use a null terminated unsigned character array. So it stops at first null character. It is even explicit in your code.

```
for(int i = 0; ch[i] != '\0'; i++)
    printf("log: %c\n", ch[i]);
```

(the relevant part being `ch[i] != 0`)

That's why you loose everything after first null character.